# Kubeflow bug deleting pipelines

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I had working pipelines in kubeflow, but recently when I go to the dashboard, I get 'No graph to show' when it should be showing the pipeline components. I have done nothing to pipeline to cause this, making me think it is a Kubeflow bug. If I try to start a run, I get 'pipeline spec is invalid'. This has happened multiple times and can be temporarily fixed by reuploading the pipeline yaml file.

I have gone through my code to find all places where the kfp client is used to interact with Kubeflow. The only places that delete are only using kfp.delete_run. Is there any way that deleting a run can cause issues to the pipeline spec?

I tried delete pipeline runs the same way my kfp client does, but have not been able to replicate the issue.